# How to make GWT/GXT RichTextEditor Tooltip unselectable?

Tags: javascript, java, css, gwt, gxt

I have a RichTextEditor class (extended from com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.LayoutContainer) in which I use a (own) tooltip class for text tooltips for links like this: https://jsfiddle.net/hkyLgam6/.

In my project the tooltips are only shown when you hover over the link but that's maybe not important.

To be able to properly delete the links and other things, I want to make the tooltips unselectable. Because every time you select the link (in example by double clicking on it) the tooltip text gets selected too and the link removing fails in example.

Trying to prevent that with CSS (like in the jsfiddle example above):

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: -moz-none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

didn't work so I would be very grateful for any idea to accomplish that.

Comment: In Chrome and Firefox at least, the example in that jsfiddle is unselectable, either by dragging the mouse over it, or double clicking the test link. Can you be more specific about the use case that doesn't work (which browser, OS, how to cause the issue, and if the jsfiddle doesn't have the problem, don't include it)?

Comment: That's right the jsfiddle example shows the desired behavior. Just my Texteditor doesn't. On current Windows and Mac versions with diverse versions of Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forget the CSS for Internet Explorer (at least older ones):

```
-ms-user-select: none;
```